# How to use all extracted values from JSON Path Extractor in next Http request?

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

i have created a scenario where i log in and extract all the device IDs added in my application. After extracting all device IDs with "JSON Path Extractor" i want to apply one configuration to all devices, using device IDs.

in JSON Path Extractor i am using JSON path as:
$..deviceResponseList[*].id[0]

and Variable name: device_id

in next http request i am calling  variable as:
${device_id}

Here if it extracts say 10 device IDs in last Http request its taking only first ID in Http request.

How should i pass every device_id extracted one after other from json path extractor in next http request sampler

NOTE: I am using Rest API for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible OOTB with jmeter-plugins.

But you can have a look at :

- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easy-scripting-of-json-applications-with-apache-jmeter/

> Use our ULP_JSON PostProcessor to extract from the JSON data the elements we want using the variable “data” extracted by previous Post-Processor...

Disclaimer : We are providers of this commercial plugin for [Apache JMeter](http://ubikloadpack.com)